# Adding a product tag next to WooCommerce product name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode, hook-woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce plugin with extension called Bundled product.

When someone views the item, it would show like [this](https://www.betterce.com/product/property-and-casualty-agent-24-hour-package/).

As you can see from the link, it displays the title of bundled product.

I am trying to see if I can add a product tag next to the title.

[image]

I believe this should be possible via hooks and filters but i am not quite sure how exactly I could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm new to Woocommerce.

Yes. You can add tags next to the product title... but the plugin as a different structure and more information is needed to know which hook to apply.
An example (This code will Run on Single Product page);

I suggest check the sourcecode of the plugin to see if you can modify that template.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_product_loop_tags', 31 );
function woocommerce_product_loop_tags() {
    global $post, $product;

    $tag_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ) );
    $idProducto=$product->id;
     $product->get_title();
    $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );

    $producto= wc_get_product( $idProducto );
    $Titulo=$producto->get_title();
    echo $Titulo." : ".$product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );
}
```

The above code will show this:
100 ~etc is the name of the product, and The text in bold are the tags.